# Errores al subir archivos mayores a 2 MB en una aplicación web hecha en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fileupload

Acabo de hacer un controlador para una aplicación hecha en `Laravel 5.5`, cuándo subo archivos con un tamaño menor o igual a 2 MB los archivos se ejecutan bien según las lógica de los controladores, pero cuando intento subir un archivo con un tamaño mayor se producen errores de servidor o los archivos se corrompen al ser descargados, este es el controlador que realiza la subida de archivos:

```
   public function subirInformes(Request $request, $idPaciente) {
        $model = new Model;
        $model->data_id = $request->input('data_id');
        $model->data2_id = $request->input('data2_id');
        $model->tipo_archivo = $request->input('tipo-archivo');
        if ($request->has('espeficique-tipo')) {
            $model->especificar_tipo = $request->input('espeficique-tipo');
        }
        $model->path = $request->file('file-archivo')->getClientOriginalName();

        if ($request->has('file-archivo')) {
            $request->file('file-archivo')->storeAs('directorio',
                $request->file('file-archivo')->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        $model->save();
        return redirect()->route('algunaruta',
            $request->input('data_id')
        );
    }
```

Y esta la configuración del `filesytems.php`

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

Mi duda es sí es **un error en la lógica del controlador o sí puedo darle más espacio para que la aplicación pueda aceptar archivos de hasta 5 MB**

Comment: es la conf de php en tu server

Answer (score 2):

Debes cambiar los valores máximos permitidos por PHP.

[Busca](https://www.templatemonster.com/es/blog/2018/04/24/donde-encontrar-el-archivo-php-ini/) tu fichero `php.ini` y cambia estos valores:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

> **NOTAS**
>
> Este tipo de variable no es posible cambiarla en tiempo de ejecución mediante la función [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).
>
> Quizá sea necesario aumentar también el valor de
>   [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
>   para subir archivos grandes.